# Design a friends table for a social networking site

Tags: mysql

Hi i am facing problem regarding the structure of a table for storing the all the friends list of an user. In the below table which i have used if user **84** has requested for friendship with user **70** & **74** then user **84** is friends are **70 & 74** and vice versa. Similarly user **77**  with **84**.

[image]

But the problem is that if i want to find out all the friends and their detail of user **84** i.e. of user (**70,74,77**).

Should i enter duplicate record like image 2 Ex: if user **84** send friend request to user **70** when user **70** accept the request then another row will be inserted like **user_id 70 & friend_id 84**.

OR is there any mysql query to join with users table based on the column value of the friends table. Like if **user_id is 84** it will join based on the **friend_id** and if **friend_id is 84** then it will join with user table by using the **user_id** column.

[image]

Comment: You can easily do a JOIN  or UNION in order to get all records for particular user_id or friend_id, so you don't need to add dups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that in your system friendship is symmetrical, i.e. if A is friends with B that implies that B is also friends with A.  In which case, I suggest that you change your Friend table's columns to reflect the fact that the two people have equal status in the relationship e.g.

*Friend*

- @ User1_Id
- @ User2_Id

With that in place, you could do a query something like this

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.UserId IN (
    (SELECT User1_Id FROM Friend WHERE User2_Id = MY_USER_ID)
    UNION
    (SELECT User2_Id FROM Friend WHERE User1_Id = MY_USER_ID)
)
```

This uses a sub-select rather than a join, plus a union to get a single list of friends' user ids depending on which way around the users are listed in the Friend table.  Documentation of [sub-query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) and [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

It's probably worth keeping it like this, rather than simplifying the code by having 2 rows in your Friends table for each relationship - (A, B) and (B, A). If you have N users the Friends table will have up to N*(N-1) rows if you duplicate and half that if you don't.

Comment: Hi @Bob Salmon i feel your answer is 100% correct but can you please differentiate between the answer given by mitkosoft which is also working fine.

Comment: @mitkosoft's answer is also good.  There are 3 differences: 1. mitkosoft uses the current schema whereas mine is based on a small schema change, 2. mitkosoft's answer is basically the inner part of my answer (the bit inside the IN clause), 3. the UNION has a different modifier - in mine it defaults to DISTINCT, but mitkosoft's answer is ALL.  In terms of results returned, in your case I don't think it will matter as I assume there won't be any duplicates.  I expect that ALL will run more quickly as it's not doing any duplicate checking, but it's a good habit to worry about duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Salmon for you valuable answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing this my suggestion is to use below structure to handle this issue. Create two different table. 
Namely 
1- Frindship 
2- FreindshipStatus

1-[image]

2-[image]

In friendship table when userId1 sends friend request to userId2 then recoed get inserted with status as 1. As userId2 accepts friend request then status becomes 2. If userid2 Canceled request then status become 3. 
And even if u want to fetch data. supposeu want to find who is friend with user id 3. Then use query like this-

```
SELECT userId1, userId2 from friendship where userId2=3 OR userId1 =3 AND status =2
```

No need to enter duplicate entries.

Comment: Hi @Santosh the problem is not with finding the friends ids but i want to fetch the friends data by using join. Suppose i want find all the friends  of user **3** and their details for above table for row 1,2,3 it should show user record based on userid2 and for 4 & 5 it will be based on userid1.

Comment: @pkk- yes,sure you can find friends data by using joints or by query of query as well.I have tried same social networking site project couple of days before, i have face from problem with database table structure as i move to further module like profile, profile views(own,friendsand public),shared picture,likes etc its is become complicated. So I came with this simple table structure.Which is really help to me.

Comment: So this is actually a good solution because, we are adding a "condition" in the relationship and we can filter the "relation ship condition" that we are interested with. In this case should be worth to INDEX the 'status' column

Answer (score 1):

You can use join query to fetch the result. No need for adding duplicate entries

Comment: Hi, we can't use join here directly as the column by which we will join with the users table is dynamic i.e. sometime its the user_id and somtimes it friends_id.

Comment: @pkk We can use. I already used such query. So only i suggest this. do you have any proof for your comment?

Comment: Hi @sujivasagam actually i just want fetch users data(use join) based on the column values. For ex if user_id = 84 then join using friend_id and vice versa. Can you please write the query for that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on first table design, you can use UNION for that in order to get all friends for particular user ID:

```
SELECT f.friend_id FROM friends f WHERE f.user_id = 84
UNION ALL
SELECT f.user_id FROM friends f WHERE f.friend_id = 84
```

Output is:

```
+-----------+
| friend_id |
+-----------+
|        70 |
|        74 |
|        77 |
+-----------+
3 rows in set
```

Comment: Hi @mitkosoft you query working 100% fine. Here is the modified query  **SELECT friends.friend_id AS friend_id,users.* FROM friends LEFT JOIN users ON(friends.friend_id=users.id) WHERE friends.user_id = 84
UNION ALL
SELECT friends.user_id AS friend_id,users.* FROM friends LEFT JOIN users ON(friends.user_id=users.id)   WHERE friends.friend_id = 84** . Can we use order by clause here to sort the data?

Comment: Also can we use limit for fetching no of records to be fetched?

Comment: Yes, you can in two ways - to add limit in each query or to make parent SELECT over entire UNION resultset.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM friends AS f 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON f.user_id = u.user_id 
     AND f.friend_id = u.user_id 
WHERE f.friend_id = 84 OR f.user_id = 84
```

I didn't try this but hope will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all the entries that includes user XXXX's friends

```
select * from friendshipTable where user_id = XXXX or friend_id = XXXX
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but i want to use join for fetching the friends record as well.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a long time i found the best way to solve the problem by using a join operation as below and also without entering duplicate entries.
Here is my query

```
SELECT  users.*  FROM friends  
  LEFT JOIN users  ON  
    (users.`id` = friends.`user_id` OR  users.`id` = friends.`friend_id`) 
        AND  
    users.`id` != '84'   
WHERE     
    friends.`user_id` = '84'   
        OR  
    friends.`friend_id`='84'
```

I have made user_id=84 as static one can make that dynamic as per the requirement.